# C++ Class inheritance, how the constructor should look like?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I want to write a code that calculates how many $ have to be paid as phone bills by clients.

I would like to have 3 type of contracts:

Basic: 10$/minute, 5$/SMS

SMSGod: 10$/minute, 1$/SMS and first 150 SMS free

Upgraded: 5$/minute, 3$/SMS and first 25 SMS free

I would like to build it something like this:

A class that contains the price the client have to pay for phoning and SMS:

```
class BaseClass 
{
private: 
   int minutesPrice; 
   int SMSPrice;
public:
    setMinutesPrice(int x) { minutesPrice = x; }
    setSMSPrice(int x) { SMSPrice = x; }
};
```

And 3 descendant class what are the type of contracts you could see above:

```
class Basic : public BaseClass 
{
public:
    Basic()
    {
        setMinutesPrice(10);
        setSMSPrice(5);
    }
}

class SMSGod : public BaseClass
{
private: 
   int freeSMS;
public: 
   SMSGod() 
   {
       setMinutesPrice(10);
       setSMSPrice(1);
       freeSMS = 150;
   }
}

class Upgraded: public BaseClass
{
private: 
   int freeSMS;
public: 
   Upgraded() 
   {
       setMinutesPrice(5);
       setSMSPrice(3);
       freeSMS = 25;
   }
}
```

Then a Client class:

```
class Client: public BaseClass
{
public:
    string name;
    string phoneNumber;
    string typeOfContract;
    int talkedMinutes;
    int sentSMS;
public:
Client(...){...}
};
```

And here is my problem. How am I supposed to make the Client() constructor, to be able to build a Client first_client(...); object. How am I supposed to call the right constructor: *Basic*, *SMSGod* or *Upgraded* based on *typeOfContract*.

This should work:

```
Client Jack("Jack", "444-468-745", "Upgraded", 50, 25);
```

Then another function aswell what calculates the bill based on how many minutes he talked *(50)*, how many SMS he sent *(25)*, and from the third parameter *("Upgraded")* I can use getter functions to know what is the base price of people who got the "Upgraded" contract, and how many free SMS they got.

(This should work at the end to calculate the phone bill:

```
int havetopay(Client x)
{
   int freeSMS = x.getFreeSMS();
   int sentSMS = x.getSentSMS();
   int SMS;
   if (freeSMS > sentSMS) SMS = 0;
       else SMS = sentSMS - freeSMS;
   return (SMS * x.getSMSPrice() + x.getTalkedMinutes() * x.getMinutesPrice());
}
```

)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would say this sounds like a classic instance of the strategy pattern, where you have clients separate from their plans. The plan is held by the client as a composition and can be interchanged whenever needed. The client object should delegate all plan related calculations to the plan itself.

Comment: Use template maybe? `Client<Upgraded> Jack("Jack", "444-468-745", 50, 25);`

Answer (score 0):

Your client class can be template class and based on template parameter passed proper constructor will be called :

```
template <class T>
class Client:public T
{
  private:
     T Obj;
  public:
     T getObject() const
     {
        return Obj;
     } 

};
Client<SMSGod> c;

template<class T>
int havetopay(Client<T> clientObj)
{
   auto x = clientObj.getObject();
   int freeSMS = x.getFreeSMS();
   int sentSMS = x.getSentSMS();
   int SMS;
   if (freeSMS > sentSMS) SMS = 0;
       else SMS = sentSMS - freeSMS;
   return (SMS * x.getSMSPrice() + x.getTalkedMinutes() * x.getMinutesPrice());
}
```

Then you can change havetopay to be templated function as well

Comment: Sounds something that can be really good for me. Can I pass the template arguments as a variable? like Client<typeOfContract> c; ?

Comment: Yes you can pass template class object as function argument

Comment: I have to correct myself: I would pass a string as template argument: string contract = "Upgraded"; Client<contract> c;

Answer (score 0):

As I Stated in my comment, I don't think that the Client class should inherit from the class that handles the plan details and calculations since that ties them together incorrectly. It is also quite reasonable to want to change plans dynamically and therefore making Client a template class with the plan as its type also ties them together unnecessarily (although it saves a little coding perhaps). I suggest something along the lines of:

```
class BasePlan 
{
private: 
   int minutesPrice; 
   int SMSPrice;
public:
    setMinutesPrice(int x) { minutesPrice = x; }
    setSMSPrice(int x) { SMSPrice = x; }
    virtual int calculateBill(int minutesTalked, int smsSent) = 0;
};

class Basic : public BasePlan 
{
public:
    Basic()
    {
        setMinutesPrice(10);
        setSMSPrice(5);
    }
    virtual int calculateBill(int minutesTalked, int smsSent) { return minutesTalked * minutesPrice + smsSent * SMSPrice;}
}

class SMSPlan : public BasePlan
{ 
private: 
   int freeSMS;
public: 
   SMSPlan(int minutesPrice, int smsPrice, int freeSMS) 
   {
       setMinutesPrice(minutesPrice);
       setSMSPrice(smsPrice);
       setFreeSMS(freeSMS);
   }

   public setFreeSMS(int free) { this.freeSMS = free; }

   virtual int calculateBill(int minutesTalked, int smsSent) { 
      int billedSMS = (freeSMS > sentSMS) ? 0 : sentSMS - freeSMS;
      return minutesTalked * minutesPrice + billedSMS * SMSPrice;}
}

class SMSGod : public SMSPlan 
{
public: 
   SMSGod() : SMSPlan(10, 1, 150)
   {
   }
}

class Upgraded: public SMSPlan 
{
public: 
   Upgraded() : SMSPlan(5, 3, 25) 
   {
   }
}

class Client
{
public:
    string name;
    string phoneNumber;
    BasePlan* currentPlan;
    int talkedMinutes;
    int sentSMS;
public:
Client(...){...}
void setPlan(BasePlan* plan) { this->currentPlan = setPlan(plan);}
int getBill() { return this->currentPlan->calculateBill(talkedMinutes, sentSMS); }
};
```

Now you can create a client first, and then set its plan to whichever plan you like whenever you like (you may want to force constructing it with a default plan just to make sure it always has one and avoid null checks):

```
Client Jack = new Client("Jack", "444-468-745", 50, 25);
Jack.setPlan(new Upgraded());
int JacksBill = Jack.getBill();
```

I also don't think it makes a lot of sense to set the talked minutes and sent sms in the constructor to the client, but that's up to you.